# Using GraphQL, Is SQL injection possible via an attribute with a datatype of Int?

Tags: graphql, sql-injection

If I have an input type:

```
input EntityInput {
  id: Int!
  vals: [Int!]!
}
```

And I have a mutation that is implemented via building a SQL string in JavaScript from the input array

```
type Mutation {
  updateEntity(input: [EntityInput!]!): [Entity!]!
}
```

Considering that the inputs are numbers, is SQL injection possible? I'm aware that for attributes of type `String`, SQL injection is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/draft/#sec-Int.Input-Coercion):

> When expected as an input type, only integer input values are accepted. All other input values, including strings with numeric content, must raise a query error indicating an incorrect type. If the integer input value represents a value less than -2³¹ or greater than or equal to 2³¹, a query error should be raised.

In other words, any non-integer value that's provided will throw an error during validation, before any of your resolver code is touched. An invalid query will not be executed at all, so an injection attack wouldn't be possible.

However, you should not rely on GraphQL's type system to prevent injection. Instead, you should ensure that you're properly escaping all user inputs used in any SQL queries you execute. Most popular ORMs, query builders, etc. do this for you already or at least offer a way to run safe, parameterized queries. Otherwise, you should use a more popular, well-tested library to do so.

Comment: What does an integer value representing a number below - 231 or above/equal to 231 mean?

Comment: @ZachSmith Oops. Lost the formatting when I copy and pasted. Those should have been exponents. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you - I thought that might mean it was possible somehow to pass untyped data to a GraphQL API that is then coerced. Not sure if that makes any sense